# getting data from multiple dynamic contols in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have created a partial view

```
@model chPayroll.Models.HREducation.HRInfo
 @{
      var list = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)TempData["PassedDivision"];
      var list1 = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)TempData["Country"];
 }
 <table >
       @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.StaffId)
   <tr>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Country, list1, "-select-",null)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Board)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Level)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PassedYr)</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PassedDivision, list, "-selected-",null)</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I am calling this partial view multiple times from controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult BlankEditorRow(string search)
        {
            HRInfo aa = new HRInfo();
            TempData["PassedDivision"] = extract.getDivision();
            TempData["Country"] = extract.getCountry();
            aa.StaffId=(Convert.ToInt16(search));
            return PartialView("ViewUserControl1",aa);

        }
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult BlankEditorRow(HRInfo ob)
   {
     extract.SaveEdu(ob);
    }
```

I can get the value one at a time i.e when the partial view is called once it works fine.But when i have to get values from two or multiple partial view it is not working.Is there any way of getting multiple datas at once?

Comment: Make a view with the model List<HRInfo> instead of calling 30 times a partial view, you will call only one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in some of my codes, wish it can help:

```
@Html.TextBox(Model.ID + ".Country", Model.Country)
...
```

so when i want to get value from multi values, just use the UpdateModel(myModel, Model.ID.ToString()).

Is that what u need?